# When choosing a Docker container image file for my Ubuntu, what do I need to match between them?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, docker

When choosing a Docker container image file for my Ubuntu, so that it can run on my Ubuntu, what do I need to match between them?

Do I need to choose image files for Linux but not for Unix (MacOS, OpenBSD)?

Do I need to match their Linux distributions (Ubuntu, Centos, ...) or just Linux kernels?

Do I need to match their Linux kernel versions?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't match Linux kernel, it's container, not virtual machine. So it can and only can run any LINUX userspace. Of course, after all, it's not real machine, depending on your configuration, some apps in it might still break, I believe.

Comment: See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html to get the general idea of namespace functionality in Linux kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the operating system must match.

Docker running on Linux can run any Linux container, but not any Windows container or *BSD container (if any even exist).

Docker running (natively) on Windows can run any Windows container, but not any Linux container.

Docker running in a Linux virtual machine on a Windows hypervisor can run any Linux container, but not any Windows container.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to match their Linux distributions (Ubuntu, Centos, ...) or just Linux kernels?

Do I need to match their Linux kernel versions?

Comment: No, you don't need to match distributions or kernel versions. Any really does mean any.

Comment: May I ask why not?

Comment: Are you really asking why a wholly artificial restriction does not exist?

Comment: The execution environments provided by different Linux distributions or different Linux kernel versions are different, so how can Docker image file be not Linux distribution or kernel version specific?

Comment: The container itself contains the complete userland. The host distribution is completely irrelevant.

Comment: What are the Linux distribution and kernel version when running something inside a container? Are they the same as the hosing/underlying Linux distribution and kernel version?

Comment: The files come from the container distro, the kernel is the one from the host.

Comment: @xenoid Thanks. What are "the files"?

Comment: @tim Executables, libraries, all the configuration in `/etc`... You don't see any external files/directories unless the are explicitly mounted as volumes.

Comment: Occasionally a Linux kernel comes along that requires updated userland code. Around 2003 there was a kernel update that required a new libprocps, or ps would fail. So, yes, some programs in a suitably old, no longer supported GNU/Linux distro could fail to run in a container running on a modern kernel.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510756/why-does-a-centos-docker-container-says-

Answer (score 1):

The container is just a process that runs in a network and filesystem "bubble". It doesn't depend on any files from its host. So container image just needs to match the type of its host (Linux on Linux, etc...). I have run Debian-based containers on RHEL and Centos and Centos containers on Ubuntu.

The "distro" of a container image is only relevant if:

- you install further software in the Dockerfile (`apt install`, `yum install`, etc...)
- you do specific system-level tweaks where config files can be in different places (security certificates, for instance).
- you add software that relies on specific libraries (for instance Alpine-based container images don't have `glibc`, so regular Linux apps require specific compiles, or glib should be added)
- you do some manual maintenance/debug in running containers (`docker exec...`) in which case having your favorite tools can help.

... but this is mostly a matter of convenience, not of compatibility.

If you have several different images, it can be useful to derive them all from the same base distro image, to let docker share the common base across the images (reduced filesystem needs...)

An application in a container could in theory rely on a system call which requires a minimum kernel version in the host machine, but this must be very rare in practice.