# Why does a CentOS Docker container says it is Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, docker, proc, version

I am trying to verify [When choosing a Docker container image file for my Ubuntu, what do I need to match between them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498198/when-choosing-a-docker-container-image-file-for-my-ubuntu-what-do-i-need-to-mat)

On Lubuntu, a CentOS container says it is CentOS, by

```
$ sudo docker run centos bash -c "cat /etc/*-release "
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

but also says it is the same Ubuntu as the host:

```
$ sudo docker run centos bash -c "cat /proc/version"
Linux version 4.15.0-46-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-038) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019


$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.15.0-46-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-038) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019
```

1. I wonder why the two commands differ in OS distribution and kernel version?
2. Does a container share the same kernel as its host? If yes, should their kernel versions be the same? [When choosing a Docker container image file for my Ubuntu, what do I need to match between them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498198/when-choosing-a-docker-container-image-file-for-my-ubuntu-what-do-i-need-to-mat#comment916943_498209) says "you don't need to match distributions or kernel versions."

Comment: So you’ve asked a question, been given an answer, which you’ve accepted, but you don’t believe it?

Comment: I want to verify if a container and its host must have the same version of kernel, since they are said to share the same Linux kernel. I am not sure how to understand his comment.

Comment: Have you looked at the resources I suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510407/what-is-a-docker-container-from-linuxs-point-of-view#comment943442_510407)? I think that would help you understand all this better.

Comment: "Does a container share **the same** kernel as its host? If **yes**, should their kernel versions be the same?" Don't you even read your own post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cat /proc/version` is showing kernel version. As containers run on the same kernel as the host. It is the same kernel as the host.

`cat /etc/*-release` is showing the distribution release. It is the OS version, minus the kernel.

A container is not virtualisation, in is an isolation system that runs directly on the Linux kernel. It uses the kernel name-spaces, and cgroups. Name-spaces allow separate networks, process ids, mount points, users, hostname, Inter-process-communication. cgroups allows limiting resources.

Answer (score 3):

1. I can't find in the provided output the CentOS Kernel info, only the version release (7.6.1810);
2. Yes, the container shares the kernel of the host machine.

Update: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33132462/2237660) answer.

Comment: I don't understand the first point: It does not look like an answer, but I can't tell for sure, as it does not look like a sentence.

Comment: My (possibly incorrect) interpretation is that JucaPirama looked for a "differ(ence) in OS distribution and kernel version" and did not see any indication of a different kernel version in the /etc/release output.

Comment: English is not my mother language, so let me try again: I could not find in the `cat /etc/*-release` output nothing concerning Kernel Version (because it is not there). So, the question itself makes no sense.